# Masking: Mask everything after a specified token (eos)

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, seq2seq

My `tgt` tensor is in shape of `[12, 32, 1]` which is `sequence_length, batch_size, token_idx`.

What is the best way to create a mask which has ones for entries with `<eos>` and before in sequence, and zeros afterwards?

Currently I'm calculating my mask like this, which simply puts zeros where `<blank>` is, ones otherwise.

`mask = torch.zeros_like(tgt).masked_scatter_((tgt != tgt_padding), torch.ones_like(tgt))`

But the problem is, that my `tgt` can contain `<blank>` as well (before `<eos>`), in which cases I don't want to mask it out.

My temporary solution:

```
mask = torch.ones_like(tgt)
for eos_token in (tgt == tgt_eos).nonzero():
    mask[eos_token[0]+1:,eos_token[1]] = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to create a mask for the PAD tokens. There are several ways. One of them is as follows.

```
# tensor is of shape [seq_len, batch_size, 1]
tensor = tensor.mul(tensor.ne(PAD).float())
```

Here, `PAD` stands for the index of the `PAD_TOKEN`. `tensor.ne(PAD)` will create a byte tensor where at `PAD_TOKEN` positions, 0 will be assigned and 1 elsewhere.

---

If you have examples like, `"<s> I think <pad> so </s> <pad> <pad>"`. Then, I would suggest using different PAD tokens, for before and after `</s>`.

OR, if you have the length information for each sentence (in the above example, the sentence length is 6), then you can create the mask using the following function.

```
def sequence_mask(lengths, max_len=None):
    """
    Creates a boolean mask from sequence lengths.
    :param lengths: 1d tensor [batch_size]
    :param max_len: int
    """
    batch_size = lengths.numel()
    max_len = max_len or lengths.max()
    return (torch.arange(0, max_len, device=lengths.device)  # (0 for pad positions)
            .type_as(lengths)
            .repeat(batch_size, 1)
            .lt(lengths.unsqueeze(1)))
```

Comment: Yes, I want to create a mask for the PAD tokens, but for my use case, it's possible that the tgt can contain PAD tokens as well, made-up example: "<s> I think <pad> so </s> <pad> <pad>", in this case I don't want to ignore the first PAD token.

Comment: I don't have the lengths available (at least not with additional effort). I came up with a temporary solution (see original post), temporary as it's using ``for`` loop. I don't know if there is a way without lengths and without for loop.